# Python: How to specify values on axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

This is my first python graph.
The following question is on plotting students percentage (0-100%).
I am trying to set my x-axis values as [0, 10, 20 up to 100] and display bars in the intervals. The problem is the x-axis only gets 5 values and they are unsorted. I have to display data and plot a graph on each coloumn of excel sheet, that is why i have written the method.
[I have attached this graph which i am getting from following code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJcX9.png)

```
    import xlrd as x
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1


    excelFile = 'cal1.xls'
    workBook = x.open_workbook(excelFile)
    workSheet = workBook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
    rows = workSheet.nrows
    cols = workSheet.ncols

    def getData_Excel(col):

        list = []

        for count in range(1, rows, 1):

            list.append(workSheet.cell_value(count, col))
            print("\nStudent ", count, " : ", list[count-1:count])

        print()

        return list

    print("Students Matric Marks:")

    matricData = [getData_Excel(3)]

    matricLegend = ['Matric %']
    plt1.hist(matricData, histtype = 'bar', color = 'blue', rwidth = 0.8)
    plt1.xlabel('Percentage')
    plt1.ylabel('Number of Students')
    plt1.xticks(range(0, 110, 10))
    plt1.yticks(range(0, 160, 20))
    plt1.title("Matric Marks")
    plt1.legend(matricLegend)
    plt1.show()
```

Comment: This is strange... Which version of matplotlib are you using. Add this line before `plt1.show`:  `plt.gca().set_xticklabels(range(0, 110, 10))`, see if it fixes things? Also no need for brackets for the line: `matricData = getData_Excel(3)`

Comment: I am using matplotlib 2.2.2 on visual studio 17.
        `plt.gca().set_xticklabels()' didnt change the graph, it was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I know perfectly what you mean, in terms of your problem, you should use `bar` while not `hist`.

`matricData` which is put on y-axis, gets the number of students. x-axis represents the interval of scores. So you can code like this:

```
matricData = [getData_Excel(3)]

matricLegend = ['Matric %']
x = list(np.arange(0, 110, 10))  #changed
plt1.bar(x, matricData, width=8) #
plt1.xlabel('Percentage')
plt1.ylabel('Number of Students')
plt1.xticks(range(0, 110, 10))   #
plt1.yticks(range(0, 160, 10))   #
plt1.title("Matric Marks")
plt1.legend(matricLegend)
plt1.show()
```

I tried that code with a sample:

`matricData=[110, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]`

Then I get the ideal result as the following diagram:
[image]